# Trying Demo Hue online- SQL server not connecting

Tags: hive, hue

I am trying the online demo HUE provided -
https://demo.gethue.com/hue/accounts/login?next=/

It is showing error- "(MySQLdb.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.31.6.77:3306' (111)") (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)".

It is not loading any DBs of the SQL server. please help on how to troubleshoot this issue

Not sure on what need to be done to fix this issue.

Comment: its a free service, currently its down. Pls try after sometime `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
`